# Message via TCP in local network is not delivered from client to server with no obvious reason

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, windows-phone

I wanted to send message to the server in local network from `WindowsPhone`. Server IP is `192.168.0.13` and port is `13000`.

```
   using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
namespace PhoneApp3 {
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage {
        public MainPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void sendMessage() {
            var asyncEvent = new SocketAsyncEventArgs { RemoteEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint("192.168.0.13", 13000) };
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SOMETHING" + Environment.NewLine);
            asyncEvent.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Socket connection = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();        
            connection.ConnectAsync(eventArgs);
            connection.SendAsync(asyncEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

So it does not freeze. The server is fine because it does handle TCP messages from other sources. **But the message is not received. Ther is no error, nothing. What do am I missing here?**

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace HomeSecurity {
    class TCPEventServer {
        private TcpListener tcpListener;
        private Thread listenThread;

        public TCPEventServer() {
            this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 13000);
            this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
            this.listenThread.Start();
        }
        private void ListenForClients() {
            this.tcpListener.Start();
            while (true) {

                TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                 System.Media.SoundPlayer notificationPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("beep.wav");
                 notificationPlayer.Play();
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("przyszlo cos");

                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
                clientThread.Start(client);
            }
        }
        private void HandleClientComm(object client) {
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
            NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            byte[] message = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("przyszlo cos");
            while (true) {
                bytesRead = 0;
                try {

                    bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("przyszlo cos");

                } catch {

                    break;
                }
                if (bytesRead == 0) {

                    break;
                }
                //wiadomość została pomyślnie odczytana
                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

                string messageDecoded = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
                messageDecoded = messageDecoded.Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty);
                string ip = ((IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address + "";
               \
                Console.WriteLine("message: " + messageDecoded + " ip: " + ip);

                VideoStream.PassMessage(messageDecoded, ip);
            }
            tcpClient.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SendAsync is an async method. It returns before the data is actually sent. You should subscribe to asyncEvent.Completed and check for args.SocketError to make sure that data was actually sent.

Note that SendAsync requires an active connection. You should call connection.ConnectAsync and wait for connection to be established before calling connection.SendAsync():

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connectArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs { RemoteEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint("127.0.0.1", 80) };
    connectArgs.Completed += connectArgs_Completed;

    Socket connection = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    connection.ConnectAsync(connectArgs);
}

void connectArgs_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
    {
        var sendArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SOMETHING" + Environment.NewLine);
        sendArgs.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        sendArgs.Completed += sendArgs_Completed;

        e.ConnectSocket.SendAsync(sendArgs);
    }
    else
    { 
        // error
    }
}

void sendArgs_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
    {
        // data sent
    }
    else
    {
        // error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited code in the orignal post. How to subscribe to that events? I tried many things even that: http://wklej.org/id/1264158/ but it didnn't work. I try to solve that for 28 hours with no break. Could you please correct my code...I do not know what else I can do.

Comment: Also check the return type of your asynchronous calls to verify that they didn't execute synchronously.

Comment: Yoda, you should wait for connection to be established. Please check my edit for complete sample.

Comment: @PashaPash You are my hero :D . I'll create bounty in 2 days when it will be avaiable to reward this answer.